# How to add metabox.io inside posttype / postmeta?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I try to integrate [metabox.io](https://metabox.io/docs/getting-started/)  in my own custom postmeta plugin,

i was tried to move the add filter code to my plugin file,

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'      => __( 'Test Meta Box', 'textdomain' ),
        'post_types' => 'post',
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'   => 'name',
                'name' => __( 'Name', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'gender',
                'name'    => __( 'Gender', 'textdomain' ),
                'type'    => 'radio',
                'options' => array(
                    'm' => __( 'Male', 'textdomain' ),
                    'f' => __( 'Female', 'textdomain' ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'id'   => 'email',
                'name' => __( 'Email', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'email',
            ),
            array(
                'id'   => 'bio',
                'name' => __( 'Biography', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'textarea',
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

but the metabox only shown in main post not in my postmeta?

How to add metabox.io in my custom postmeta?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i read your question right, you are trying to add this to your own metabox that your plugin uses.

Given that, you could mess around with the filters and code for where it puts the data, but you might be better off forking the project from github and rewriting the interface for it as suits your needs. This is of course assuming the license allows it.

Having used the plugin before personally though, you should be able to customize how it looks and functions on the dashboard by writing admin hooks and filters as well.

If I was wrong about what you were asking, let me know and I'll try again.

Comment: I just want to add metabox.io in postmeta or posttype, i also was tried official [mb posttype] (https://metabox.io/plugins/custom-post-type/) but i don't have any idea to custom the posttype that i aready made with metabox

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, finally i found the answer

To integrate with posttype, i just need to change post_types in line 5

```
'post_types' => 'post',
```

with my own posttype.

Comment: You should be able to add it for different taxonomies too if i recall. Its quite robust. Glad you were able to find it.